# How to make scrlttr2 look like letter

Tags: letters, scrlttr2

I need to put a subject line in a letter so after looking around most suggestions seem to point towards using the document class `scrlttr2` instead of `letter` since it is much more flexible.

However, the look of the letter when I change to `scrlttr2` becomes totally messed up from the simple `letter` format I prefer. More specifically:

1. The from address is moved to the top left instead of the right over the date.
2. OMR markers introduced on the left of the page.
3. A separate underlined from address added on the top with a different font.
4. The indentation and paragraphing is really ugly. It indents new paragraphs instead of putting whitespace. (While this is OK for a normal document, its totally ugly for a letter)
5. While the normal `letter` style allowed me to leave the address of the recipient empty like this `\begin{letter}{}`, I am forced to put something in `scrlttr2` even if I don't want to put anything. (If I leave it empty or just put a space it gives a very cryptic error `Line 0: There's no line end here` even if its not on line 0.)

Is there anyway I can make it look like the `letter`style? I am just going through this to add a subject line, so if there's a simpler way it would be equally good.

**UPDATE**

The output from `scrlttr2` when I use `\KOMAoptions{foldmarks=off,backaddress=false,fromalign=right}` is now as follows:

[image]

This is because it is inserted in the page header rather than the page content.
I need it to look at least as it is generated by `letter` as follows:

[image]

The best thing would be if it is also right aligned, but if I manage to get it like `letter` it should be enough.

Comment: Not much of a solution to your real problem, but to leave the address blank, try giving it as `~` (unbreakable space) or `\strut`. The error is probably because there's a `\\` in the expansion of the address, and it doesn't like empty lines.

Comment: Thanks, `~` works. The 'to' address is empty, there is no `\\` or anything. It took me a while to discover that it was the problem because the error line number it was reporting was 0.

Comment: I meant, the class probably inserts a line break (\\, miscoded that before) when typesetting the address. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anyway I can make it look like the letterstyle? I am just
>   going through this to add a subject line, so if there's a simpler way
>   it would be equally good.

It sounds like what you really want is to be able to add a subject line to the standard `letter` class, and that you really do not want to use `scrlttr2`. If that is the case you can just modify the `letter` class `\opening` macro. I use the `etoolbox` `\patchcmd`, but I am sure there are other ways. The key part is

```
\makeatletter
  \newcommand{\subject}[1]{\def\@subject{#1}}
  \patchcmd{\opening}{#1\par\nobreak}{\ifundef{\@subject}{}{\textbf{\@subject}\par\vspace{2\parskip}}#1\par\nobreak}{}{}
\makeatother
```

You would then specify the subject with `\subject`, just like you specify `\name`. A full MWE is

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\subject}[1]{\def\@subject{#1}}
\patchcmd{\opening}{#1\par\nobreak}{\ifundef{\@subject}{}{\@subject\par\vspace{2\parskip}}#1\par\nobreak}{}{}
\makeatother

\name{My name}
\signature{My signature}
\address{My road\\My city}
\location{My location}
\telephone{my telephone}

\subject{My subject}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{To name\\To road\\To city}
  \opening{Dear \toname}
  Hello World
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was actually looking for! The hell with `scrlttr2`, its flexible but so difficult to get something simple like the sender address on top of the date, like normal letters! I modified your suggestion a little to make the subject bold as follows: `\patchcmd{\opening}{#1\par\nobreak}{\ifundef{\@subject}{}{\textbf{\@subject}\par\vspace{2\parskip}}#1\par\nobreak}{}{}`

Answer (score 15):

The nice thing about `scrlttr2` is that it's easily customizable.

- The ORM markers you mentioned are probably the foldmarks, to be switched off using `\KOMAoptions{foldmarks=off}`
- The From address can be put to the right, check the manual for "firsthead" and "nexthead". Or take the example I put online here as a starter: [uweziegenhagen.de/?page_id=132](http://uweziegenhagen.de/?page_id=132), snippet 47 or snippet 40.
- The small back adress over the to address can be switched off using `\setkomavar{backaddress}{}` The default setting is that it is composed from 
  komavars such as `fromaddress` and `fromname`.
- EDIT: To put the address to the right you can use a simple `tabular` in  `firsthead`:

  ```
  \documentclass[12pt,english]{scrlttr2}

  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[]{babel}

  \newkomavar{fromplace}
  \setkomavar{fromname}{Some other Dude}
  \setkomavar{fromaddress}{Fairytail-Lane 1}
  \setkomavar{fromplace}{12345 Cologne}


  \firsthead{%
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.7\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}}
  & \usekomavar{fromname} \newline \usekomavar{fromaddress}  \newline \usekomavar{fromplace} 
  \end{tabular}
  }

  \begin{document}

  \begin{letter}{Some Address \\ Far, far away}
  \opening{Hello Dude,}


  \closing{Best wishes,}
  \end{letter}

  \end{document}
  ```

[image: example using tabular in firsthead]

Give `scrlttr2` a chance, I have been working with this magnificient class for proably a decade now and never stopped loving it!

Here's another approach based on your comments, I modified an existing letter template from my 'collection', so it does a few other tricks as well.

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[]{babel}

\date{} %we do that manually!

\newkomavar{fromplace} % a few koma vars
\setkomavar{fromname}{Some other Dude}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Fairytail-Lane 1}
\setkomavar{fromplace}{12345 Cologne}

\KOMAoptions{foldmarks=off,fromrule=false}
\setkomavar{backaddress}{}

\makeatletter % indention of the address fields
\@setplength{toaddrhpos}{27mm}
\@setplength{toaddrwidth}{92mm}
\@setplength{sigindent}{0mm}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}

% Define new letter header
\firsthead{
  \null\hfill
  \parbox[t][\headheight][t]{4cm}{%
  \vspace*{7cm}

\usekomavar{fromname} \newline 
\usekomavar{fromaddress}  \newline 
\usekomavar{fromplace} \vspace*{1cm}

    \today
      }
    }%


\begin{document}\raggedright

\begin{letter}{Some Address \\ Far, far away}
\opening{Hello Dude,}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mollis, felis vel eleifend elementum, lectus eros faucibus nisl, pellentesque eleifend nunc nibh sit amet nisi. Vivamus dictum, eros eu tincidunt mollis, ante odio scelerisque leo, vel pharetra risus justo id nibh. Nam mollis elementum sem, vel porttitor erat fringilla vitae. Suspendisse potenti. Cras quis orci vel elit faucibus consectetur non ut felis. In lacinia dictum congue. Vivamus vel sapien nec velit pharetra semper non nec eros. Donec laoreet mi at odio molestie varius. Nullam et ornare velit. Ut laoreet pulvinar orci, ac lobortis nisi fermentum vel.


\closing{Best wishes,}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image: another approach]

Comment: Thanks, so got the foldmarks off, and the backaddress removed. I still haven't understood how the `firsthead` and `nexthead` work because your snippet 47 is a bit too complicated, no idea what all the stuff inside it means, and snippet 40 doesn't seem to be using it. Any idea how to fix the paragraph indents and spacing between them? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I noticed that `\firsthead` really puts the address at the header of the letter, not on top of the date on the right as I want it. I want it to be on the right on top of the date just like the `letter` class does it. Is there any other way to change it to be on the right?

Comment: OK, so actually `scrlttr2` has an option `parskip=full` which does it automatically. The `\closing` indent can also be fixed with `\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}`. All's left is the from address on the right instead of the left.

Comment: Please put a picture online what you want to achieve. I'll look into it, shouldn't take long.

Comment: I added 2 pictures of how the `fromaddress` is being generated. One using `scrlttr2` and one using `letter`. I want to achieve the one generated by `letter` and ideally even better if they are right aligned to the right margin.

Comment: You can use a `tabular`environment in `firsthead`, see the updated example above.

Comment: I have already achieved that without the tabular, just by the `\KOMAoptions{fromalign=right}`, the problem is that the sender address is in the header and not immediately on top of the date. Even in your sample, the address is not aligned with the date and there is a huge vertical whitespace between the from address and the date. There should only be 1 blank line.

Comment: I think the problem is that `scrlttr2` puts the from address in the header. Is there any way not to put it there and just put it with the date on the right? Its the standard way most people do normal letters, I would be surprised if something that simple is not possible.

Comment: i see, i have another example I can modify. probably until tomorrow evening

Comment: Ok, edited my answer.